# what effects performance of a tun/tap or a virtual network interface?

Tags: linux, nic, tun

I know what a tun/tap device does in linux.

if I create a new tun interface with only a name and assigning an IP address to it, and leave other settings as default, like this:

```
sudo tunctl -t tun0
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev tun0
```

information `ip` command shows:

```
ip addr show tun0
5: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d6d0:9ac7:7828:698d/64 scope link stable-privacy
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

information `ethtool` command shows:

```
ethtool tun0
Settings for tun0:
    Supported ports: [ ]
    Supported link modes:   Not reported
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: No
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  Not reported
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: No
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Full
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: off
    MDI-X: Unknown
    Current message level: 0xffffffa1 (-95)
                   drv ifup tx_err tx_queued intr tx_done rx_status pktdata hw wol 0xffff8000
    Link detected: yes
```

this tun interface is working smoothly in my dedicated software but there are things that I don't know how do they effect the performance.

as I don't know what any specific fields do, I haven't done any benchmarks yet.

the only field I know is `MTU` and I do play with it with knowledge.

I don't need a "one solution for all problems".

I need someone help me how to study those things by providing links, articles or even some quotes about each.

I know each has alot details behind so I am ready to reserve some days to study on.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you know? https://serverfault.com/questions/994721/ping-does-not-work-on-tap-interfaces-with-bridge/996479#996479 (except yours is a TUN not a TAP, so no Ethernet nor ARP)

Comment: @A.B thanks. I know what do they do as I am using it. the question is "is there any thing effecting the performance which I'm not aware of" like that qlen